# How to multiply XMMATRIX and XMVECTOR (DirectX11)?

Tags: c++, vector, matrix, directx, directx-11

I want to multiply the vector and the matrix.
The vector is of `XMVECTOR` type and the matrix is of `XMMATRIX` type.
I cannot find any function in DirectX SDK to do it.
There is `XMMatrixMultiply` but only for two matrixs, the same for vectors - no `(vector, matrix)` function.

Comment: Cant you define a vector as a 1xN or Nx1 matrix?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [XMVector3Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector3transform%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (or [XMVector4Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.transformation.xmvector4transform%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it depends on what you want).